# How to show set of Radio buttons based on a previous Radio Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with radio buttons on it. When a user selects "unfit", I want them to go on to indicate a reason from a second set of radio buttons. I don't want those reasons displayed until they have clicked on the "unfit" radio button.

How do I accomplish this in JavaScript or jQuery?

Here's my code, sorry for the design

```html
<div class="col-xs-7">
<input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Fit") echo "checked";?> value="Fit">Fit
   <br>
<input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Unfit") echo "checked";?> value="Unfit">Unfit
   <br>
 <input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="all") echo "checked";?>value="all">All
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
  </div>
<h4>Reason for being unfit</h4>
 <hr>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="col-xs-2">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7">
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Tuberculosis") echo "checked";?> value="Tuberculosis">Tuberculosis
 br>
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Pneumonia") echo "checked";?> value="Pneumonia">Pneumonia
   <br>
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="all") echo "checked";?>value="All">All
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below,

You can archive this by **listing to the click event** of **each radio button** then **finding the id** of particular **radio box**, and checking whether it is equal to the **radio-unfit**..Then depend on that we will show the **next radio button set**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  $("#unfit-reason").hide();

  // when you click the radio check whether that is radio-unfit
  $("input[name=res]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "radio-unfit") {
      $("#unfit-reason").show();
    } else {
      $("#unfit-reason").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Fit" ) echo "checked";?>value="Fit">Fit
  <br>
  <input id="radio-unfit" type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Unfit" ) echo "checked";?>value="Unfit">Unfit
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="all" ) echo "checked";?>value="all">All
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
</div>
</div>
<div id='unfit-reason'>
  <h4>Reason for being unfit</h4>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Tuberculosis" ) echo "checked";?>value="Tuberculosis">Tuberculosis br>
        <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Pneumonia" ) echo "checked";?>value="Pneumonia">Pneumonia
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="all" ) echo "checked";?>value="All">All
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can hide the reasons when the page is loaded, then show them when the appropriate radio button is clicked.

This simple example doesn't support all the possible navigation (i.e. once you see the reasons, they remain visible). Still, it should give you the idea.

Note that it simplifies manipulation of form elements if they have unique IDs, so I've added them where needed.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
    // Hide reasons initially
    $("#unfit-reason").hide();
  
    // Show reasons when unfit is clicked
    $( "#radio-unfit" ).click(function() {
       $("#unfit-reason").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Fit") echo "checked";?> value="Fit">Fit
   <br>
<input id="radio-unfit" type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="Unfit") echo "checked";?> value="Unfit">Unfit
   <br>
 <input type="radio" name="res" <?php if (isset($res) && $res=="all") echo "checked";?>value="all">All
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
  </div>
<div id='unfit-reason'>
<h4>Reason for being unfit</h4>
 <hr>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="col-xs-2">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7">
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Tuberculosis") echo "checked";?> value="Tuberculosis">Tuberculosis
 br>
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="Pneumonia") echo "checked";?> value="Pneumonia">Pneumonia
   <br>
 <input type="radio" name="ru" <?php if (isset($ru) && $ru=="all") echo "checked";?>value="All">All
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```